# Sticky Note Gadget - Preserve Text Through Log-Out

Tags: html, xml, jscript, windows-desktop-gadgets

I am working on a very simple sticky note gadget for Windows 7. Everything is works except every time I log out, the contents of the notes get flushed. What is the best way to preserve these contents so that the text will reappear after reboot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save settings for gadgets using the `System.Gadget.Settings` object. The methods `read`/`readString` and `write`/`writeString`

The settings are preserved when the computer restarts. A quick method of testing this is ending the sidebar.exe process then starting it again (this emulates a restart in the Windows Gadget platform.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms723661(v=vs.85).aspx